# Concatenating clob cloumn values in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, string-concatenation, clob

I am using this statement in my sql query to concate large clob column values but the output contains extra ","(commas) not able to figure out what is going wrong.?

```sql
SELECT RTRIM(
         XMLAGG(
           XMLELEMENT(
             E,
             CASE WHEN UNIQ_ID IN ( SELECT VAL
                                    FROM   SOME_TABLE
                                    WHERE VAL_NM = 'SOME_TEXT' )
             THEN TABLE1.COL_NAME
             ELSE NULL
             END,
             ', '
           ).EXTRACT('//text()')
           ORDER BY TABLE1.UNIQ_ID
         ).GETCLOBVAL(),
         ','
       ) COMBINED_VAL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the trailing commas, then you are concatenating using comma then space so the trailing character is a space and not a comma.

If you are asking about adjacent separators with no value in between then when the `WHEN UNIQ_ID IN ( ... )` part of your `CASE` statement is not matched you will have a `NULL` value; this is concatenated into the aggregated output and then you will find that you have two adjacent comma-space separators with no text in between.

For example:

```sql
WITH test_data ( id, value ) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'a'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'b'  FROM DUAL
)
SELECT RTRIM(
         XMLAGG(
           XMLELEMENT(
             E,
             value,
             ', '
           ).EXTRACT('//text()')
           ORDER BY id
         ).GETCLOBVAL(),
         ','
       ) AS COMBINED_VAL
FROM   test_data;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | COMBINED_VAL |
> | :----------- |
> | a, , b,      |
> ```

The trailing comma-space isn't trimmed as the last character is a space and the values are `a` then `NULL` then `b` and the `NULL` is represented as a zero-width substring.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f975b7ec8b8654de1c19602451bde00e)*

Comment: This is the output:-> (a, , b,)  which you mentioned. I don't want the trailing commas and empty commas within. My output should be (a,b). Really appreciate if you could help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty easy:

1. do not aggregate rows which you don't want to get. To do that you just need to generate xmlelement only for required rows, and just return null for others.
2. Just put all characters you want to trim from your result into second parameter of rtrim:

```sql
SELECT RTRIM(
         XMLAGG(
           CASE WHEN UNIQ_ID IN ( SELECT VAL
                                    FROM   SOME_TABLE
                                    WHERE VAL_NM = 'SOME_TEXT' )
                  and COL_NAME is not null
                THEN XMLELEMENT(
                        E,
                        TABLE1.COL_NAME||', '
                        )
           END
           ORDER BY TABLE1.UNIQ_ID
         ).extract('//text()').GETCLOBVAL(),
         ', '
       ) COMBINED_VAL
from table1;
```

Full test case with sample data and results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=452c715247e8edda8735014ff2fb34f4

```sql
with 
 SOME_TABLE(VAL, VAL_NM) as (
    select level*2, 'SOME_TEXT' from dual connect by level<=10
 )
,TABLE1(UNIQ_ID, COL_NAME) as (
    select level UNIQ_ID
        , to_clob(level) COL_NAME
    from dual
    connect by level<=20
)
SELECT RTRIM(
         XMLAGG(
           CASE WHEN UNIQ_ID IN ( SELECT VAL
                                    FROM   SOME_TABLE
                                    WHERE VAL_NM = 'SOME_TEXT' )
                  and COL_NAME is not null
                THEN XMLELEMENT(
                        E,
                        TABLE1.COL_NAME||', '
                        )
           END
           ORDER BY TABLE1.UNIQ_ID
         ).extract('//text()').GETCLOBVAL(),
         ', '
       ) COMBINED_VAL
from TABLE1;
```

Results:

```
COMBINED_VAL
----------------------------------------
2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20
```